# Flask and Twilio Integration Issue: No Response to User Messages

Tags: python, flask, twilio, webhooks

I have been working on a Flask application that integrates with Twilio for handling WhatsApp messages. The goal of this application is to facilitate bus seat bookings through WhatsApp. However, I am encountering an issue where the application does not respond to user messages as expected.
However, when a user sends a message, the application does not respond with the intended instructions or messages, and no error messages are displayed.

```
@app.route("/Teebot", methods=['POST'])
def bot():
    global user
     # Log the entire incoming request
    app.logger.info(request.data)
    twilio_headers = request.headers
    app.logger.info(f"Twilio Headers:{twilio_headers}")
    incoming_msg = request.values.get("Body",'').lower()
    sender_number = request.values.get("From",None)
    if sender_number not in user:
        return "Welcome I see is  your first time."
    user [sender_number]={"state": "start", "next_state": "sender_number:"}
    user = user.get(sender_number, {})
    user = user[sender_number]
    messaging_response = MessagingResponse()
    if incoming_msg  in  allowed_messages:
        messaging_response.message = "Please enter a message."
    else:
         messaging_response.message = "Please start the conversation with one of the following commands: start, book, cancel,hi,hello."
    if user["state"]=="start":
             messaging_response.message = ("Welcome to bus booking. How can I serve you?\n"
                                           "Please select an option:\n"
                                           "1. Book a seat \n"
                                           "2. Cancel Booking \n")
   user["state"] = "menu"
    elif user["state"] == "menu":
         if "1" in incoming_msg:
             user["state"] = "ask_name"
             messaging_response = "May i have your name:"
         elif "2" in incoming_msg:
             messaging_response = "please call 73409887 for cancelation"
```

I need assistance in identifying the issues in the code that prevent the application from responding correctly to user messages. Additionally, I would like guidance on how to ensure that the user is guided through the booking process effectively.

I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or solutions to resolve this issue and make the application work as intended. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the code does not respond like when you send "Hi or even  1" it will not give any reponse for example it had to give a menu like  (1 . book  a seat   2. cancel / modify) but nothing  is happening  that is the big problem and it has no errors  I would like guidance on how to ensure that the user is guided through the booking process effectively.

I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or solutions to resolve this issue and make the application work as intended. Thank you for your assistance!